# Converting data from ASCII to Base 64 without an encoder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, ascii

Im trying to create two programs, one which converts data from ASCII -> integer to -> Base 64 and another which reverses the process, to test how to do this im using the following example where I input "Cat" and came up with 0b10001000110111101100111. However im having trouble transferring this to Base 64, I should end up with RG9N, im unsure what I should add to come up with this, Im new to Python & programming in general.

## Base 64 Encoder

## packing into integer

```
number = ord('C')
number = ord('a') + (number << 8)
number = ord('t') + (number << 8)

print(bin(number))

#Base64 from integer

code = number  >> (6 * 3)
number = number - (code  << (6 * 3))
code = number >> (6 * 2)
number = number - (code  << (6 * 3))
code = number >> (6 * 1)
number = number - (code << (6 * 1))

print(chr(code))
```

Comment: You could look at how it is implemented in Python's standard library. See the `base64.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need 4 print statements, not just one - each of the 4 codes that you create must be output. You might also prefer `write` to `print`, since `print` will add a space to each output.

Second, you can't just call `chr` on those codes, because they translate to unprintable characters. You need a mapping from the code number to a character, which you can find at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

The basic method you're using, which converts 3 input characters to 4 output characters, is sound. But you'll also need some special case code at the end of the sequence where you have less than 3 characters left, and you need to insert `=` padding into the output.

Comment: Great that makes sense, thank you, although im unsure how I would implement the code to character mapping. would it look something like     if 0<25:
        symbol = chr(code+ord('A')-0)
    elif 26 <= code <=51:
        symbol = chr(code + ord('a')-26)
    elif 52 <= code <=61:
        symbol = chr(code + ord('0')-52)
    elif code == 62:
        symbol = '+'

Comment: @ShahobMousavi the easiest way is to have a list, and just index into that.